# shell script to find a string and print the current line and next line recursively

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I have written a small script which searches the string and prints the current line. But m little confused to print the next line. I am ok with bash/perl/python

```bsh
#!/bin/bash  

CURRENT_DIR=`pwd`
cnt=0

for dir in $(find $CURRENT_DIR -type d)
do
    for myFile in $dir/*  
    do 
        if [ -f "$myFile" ]; then
            cat $myFile | while myLine=`line`
            do
                allFile="$myLine"    
                if echo "$myLine" | grep -q $1 ; then 
                    echo "$myFile" "$allFile" ""
                fi  
                #echo 'expr $count+1'
                #echo   "$allFile"   ""
            done #LINE  
        fi
    done #FILE
done # DIRECTORY
```

Comment: Do u want to print the next line whether or not if the matched string is present or u want it to be printed only when there is a matched string ?

Answer (score 2):

If your grep is GNU:

```
 grep -A1 pattern file
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example to you here in bash, This one considers a bunch of  text files in a directory. You can manipulate it as you need .

Within one dir

```
    grep "search string" *.txt
```

Search or go to sub-dir

```
    find /full/path/to/dir -name "*.txt" -exec grep "search string" {} ;
```

Hope this helps you .

Answer (score 0):

you  can do it using awk:

```
awk '/Message/{print;getline;print}' your_file
```

Above is for one single file.This command will show you the matched pattern line and the next line in the file.

If you want to do it recursive in all the files in a directory structure then :

```
find . -name -type f|xargs awk '/Message/{print;getline;print}'
```